# limited margin auto?

Tags: html, css, width, margin

I want to have the content of my website centred but only for a certain width of a webpage. So when it's over say 500px I'd want the content to then be fixed, unable to stretch any further. Is there anyway to do that, or am I best having everything fixed? Hope that makes sense ill add some visuals to be a bit clearer..
thanks!

http://i38.photobucket.com/albums/e126/aaron123456/stackflow.jpg

1.auto margin with a certain space
2.so content doesn't float in the middle of a larger webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple:

```
#container {
    max-width: 500px;
}

#container > * {
    margin: 1em auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

`#container` defines the maximum width, and every element placed inside it is aligned centered. I had to set the `width` to prevent these elements from requiring the entire width.

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/7DHyQ/)

Comment: is there any way to do that in the context of a pages body. got alot of div tags going on, so it's not working. what should go in '> *' sorry fairly new to this.. getting there!

Comment: `> *` selects all direct descendants of the element specified before. Which problem do you experience in your page?

Comment: it's just not really working at all. probably due to the amount of div tags already.. here's what im working with http://i38.photobucket.com/albums/e126/aaron123456/Screenshot2011-12-22at202824.png

Comment: probably just messy code right? maybe i could involve it another tag, like the main div?

Comment: Is there any CSS for `#hover_img`? And you should remove the `<br/>` elements.

Comment: #hover_img img
{
    display:none;
   white-space:nowrap;
}

#hover_img:hover img
{
    display:block;
 width:100px;
 padding-top:10px;

}'

Comment: This one shouldn't matter. Did you try to copy the HTML code of my link in your page, just instead of the current `#container`?

Comment: it justs goes straight off the page, must be some other code in the way. any chance i could email you the html file to take a look? no problems if not. its probably something really simple

Comment: Ok, let's continue the discussion via mail.

Comment: wow great. i used the email off your website. if that's no good, my emails just on my profile